# Create a row programatically Parse Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Is it possible to create a row in a class and depending on the certain variables, the fields I have created in the class are set to that? (Basically creating a row programatically using swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out myself, here is the code if others were wondering:

```
var gameScore = PFObject(className:"GameScore")
gameScore["score"] = 1337
gameScore["playerName"] = "Sean Plott"
gameScore["cheatMode"] = false
gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if (success) {
    // The object has been saved.
  } else {
    // There was a problem, check error.description
  }
}
```

An example from: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-saving/iOS